# Adding Textfields at runtime in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dynamic

I am new to php and wanted to now, how can I add text fields at runtime. I have created a php page with a simple dropdown list in it.The dropdown list has numbers 1,2,3 and so on. What I want to do is that whenever a user selects a number from dropdown list, the same number of text fields (along with labels) appear. Example 1 textfield for 1 (with label), 2 textfields for 2 and so on . If someone can give me any code example or a link to understand, It will be very helpful . Thanks alot :)

Comment: sounds like you want javascript not php. to do it with php the form would have to be submitted to create the textfields

Comment: @Dagon can you please give me any code example or a link to do it with javascript? thanks

Comment: I'm fond of the jquery Library http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jquery, a JavaScript library as Dagon suggested.
First your html:

```
<form>
  <input class="target" type="text" value="Field 1" />
  <select class="target">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="other">

</div>
```

Then your javascript (using jQuery):

```
$('.target').change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        $('#other').append("<label>" + $(this).text() + "</label><input type='text' value='' />");
    });      
});
```

For your reference:

http://api.jquery.com/change/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to help you. Use change() function ( http://api.jquery.com/change/ ) to get the drop down list value and create another jQuery function to populate the text fields.

This tutorial might help you http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do that:

```
<?php 
$num = 2; //get number input from user
for ($i = 0; $i < $num ; $i++) {
echo '<input type="text" />';
}
?>
```